# Is this inequality correct , if a,b,c are positive and $a^6+b^6+c^6=3$,then $ a+b+c \le 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I want to verify the validity of this inequality, and if it is true, I want to prove it if a,b,c
are positive and $a^6+b^6+c^6=3$,then
$$ a+b+c \le 3$$
Use an A-G inequality we get $abc \le 1$
.How can I complete this?

Comment: Look up “power mean inequality” ...

Comment: $abc \leqslant 1  \implies a+b+c \leqslant 3$ is wrong, so no way to complete that thought process. If you want to use AM-GM inequality, consider $x^6+1+1+1+1+1 \geqslant 6x$ and sum over $x \in \{a, b, c\}$.

Answer (score 3):

We have by Holder inequality: $(a+b+c)^6=(1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot a+1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot b+1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot c)^6\le (1^6+1^6+1^6)^5(a^6+b^6+c^6)= 3^6\implies a+b+c \le 3$. This means your inequality is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Actually we have this lemma:
For $a_i \geq 0, \forall i = \overline{1,n}$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = n$$
we will have this: $$\sum_{i=1}^na_i^m \geq \sum_{i=1}^na_i^n, \forall m \geq n > 0$$
This can be easily proved by Cauchy - Schwarz inequality.
So you just have to put $n=3$ and have your problem.

Comment: $i=3$? $i$ is just an index for the sums. Do you mean $n=3$?

Comment: I have changed it

Comment: How exactly the problem OP problem follows from just putting $n=3$?

Comment: It just $3=a^6+b^6+c^6 \geq a^5+b^5+c^5 \geq ... \geq a+b+c.$

Comment: If you set $n=3$, the hypothesis of your lemma is $a+b+c=3$ which we don't have.